# Cannot Connet to azure git in centos

Tags: git, azure, centos, credentials

i use azure for version control and store my codes instead of gitlab,but when i want to pull my commits into server i use git pull and the azure needs my password, when i enter my pass word the following error comes and i cannot pull my codes in server

```
 fatal: Authentication failed for 
'https://amirrezamoradi1372@dev.azure.com/amirrezamoradi1372/BMS/_git/BMS/'
```

i need to send my username and password again, i just want to find a way to git tell me please enter your username?

i searched alot and fond out i should install git credential manager but i do not know which manager is suitable for centos and how to install it
please help me to pull my codes into server
thanks

Comment: Could you please check my answer to see if it helps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are official tutorials for this: [Install the Git Credential Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-up-credential-managers?view=azure-devops#install-the-git-credential-manager) and [Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux/blob/master/Install.md#installing-on-mac-or-linux-without-a-package-manager)

And, for Linux OS, you can [Set up SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#set-up-ssh-key-authentication) which is very convenient.

At last, you can use [Personal access token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops).  When you are asked for password, you can just use the created PAT. I can successfully use it to clone and push my repository.

[image]